# Checking if link being clicked is within a whitelist array using a for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

I"m looking to check if the path of the a link being clicked is within an array of whitelisted url paths.

```
var $whiteListURL = ['/PATH1', '/PATH2'],
    $whiteListURLLen = $whiteListURL.length,
    $link = window.location.pathname,
    isFound = false;

for ( var i = 0; i < $whiteListURLLen; i++ ) {
    if ( !$.cookie('MYCOOKIE') && $link.indexOf($whiteListURL[i]) > -1 ) {
        isFound = true;
        document.location.href = $link;
        $.cookie("MYCOOKIE", $lang, { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: 'MYSITE.com' });
        break;
    }
}    

if ( isFound || !$.cookie('MYCOOKIE') ) {
    EVT.emit('fire_modal'); 
}
```

Currently it goes to the correct location but it keeps linking to the same page. Am I not breaking the loop?

Problem I'm having wrapping my head around is:

1. I have two other lists to check for. Would I write multiple FOR loops?

Comment: Where's the "link being clicked"? You're checking the *current* page (`$link = window.location.pathname`), then reloading the *same* page again (`document.location.href = $link;`).

Comment: @Paul Roub Well the link live on the homepage and if the link is inarray it should bypass the modal and display the page. So this is happening on  / then should poing to /PATH1 or / PATH2

Comment: I hope this is not for security purpose

Comment: @A.Wolff Not really, I want certain visitors to our site to bypass a modal we fire for not having a cookie. Nothing really secure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed stuck in the `for` loop, because you reload the page *before* setting the cookie:

```
document.location.href = $link; // Page will refresh now
$.cookie("MYCOOKIE", $lang, { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: 'MYSITE.com' }); // This code is never reached
```

Just switch those 2 lines from position and it should not enter the loop again after page reload.

*Sidenote*: `isFound` will never be `true` in your current code, since you reload the page after setting it to `true`, and then it gets set to `false` again in the beginning of your code.

Comment: Oh man... ugh. Thanks. It was right in front of me the whole time.